# How to match any pattern in R using a wildcard to repeat an experiment for all combinations?

Tags: regex, r

This is head(raw_data)

```
cust_acct_clsfn_key Acct_clsfn cust_gendr_code         dma_name brand_type_desc cnt_sndrs
6                    1  Consumers               M         NEW YORK       Unbranded        60
18                   3     Guests               #          CHICAGO         Branded        88
20                   1  Consumers               M      LOS ANGELES         Branded     25008
22                   1  Consumers               F DALLAS-FT. WORTH         Branded      6639
31                   1  Consumers               M   SEATTLE-TACOMA         Branded      7260
33                   1  Consumers               M DALLAS-FT. WORTH       Unbranded        44
```

I am trying to repeat an experiment for every possible permutation of Acct clsfn and brand_type_desc.
Let us say both Acct_clsfn and brand_type_desc only have 2 unique values, hence (2+1)*(2+1)=9 combinations are possible, but I am trying to write a general code.

```
a = unique(raw_data$Acct_clsfn)
b = unique(raw_data$brand_type_desc)

for (j in a)){

    for (i in b){
        raw_data_seg <- raw_data[raw_data$brand_type_desc==i,]
        doSomething(raw_data_seg)
    }
}
```

This code works in repeating the experiment for following combinations (which expand.grid will also do):

- [Consumer - Branded] [Consumer - Unbranded] [Guests - Branded]
  [Guests - Unbranded]

however it won't repeat the experiment considering the following cases which I wanted to include:

- [Both Consumer and Guest - Branded] [Both Consumer and Guest -
  Unbranded] [Consumer - Branded and Unbranded] [Guest - Branded and
  Unbranded] [Consumer and Guest - Branded and Unbranded]

What I tried and didn't work:
Extending the lists a and b, by adding 1 wildcard (similar to * in Excel) which will match any value in raw_data[raw_data$brand_type_desc==i,] and hence won't filter anything.

Thanks

PS This is my first question, please pardon any code of use violations!

Comment: In R regex, `.` reperesents anything and `*` any number of repetitions, so you can often see them combined as `.*` which means: match anything, as often as possible.

Comment: Hi @docendo discimus, I am trying to avoid regex functions/gsub to keep my code simple. Can I write something like raw_data$brand_type_desc=="*." which will work as opposed to using a function? Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at `?expand.grid`? It should enumerate possibilities for you. It is a bit unclear what relation your code example has to your description and to what you are trying to achieve. Can you post a minimal example showing what is not working and what (exactly) you are expecting.

Comment: Rusan is right, you should explain what you want to do and what you expect rather than how you want to do it. It's also not clear why you want to avoid regex generally. There are some very simple regex things you can learn/understand very easily. I also have only a basic understanding of regex, but it's already quite useful.

Comment: Thanks both, looks like I cannot avoid regex. I just wanted to know if there is a simple equivalent of asterix, which would hypothetically return TRUE for any x == "asterix", and looks like it doesn't exist in R. So I will put effort into learning regex/expand grid.

Comment: As a very basic example, if you have a vector like `x <- c("Consumers","Guests", "Consumers123")` and you want to return TRUE for all elements of X which start with "consumer" you can use `grepl("^consumer.*", x)`.